# how to install dvips for TeXlive in CentOS?

Tags: centos

I just installed `texlive` on CentOS 5.4 and can't find `dvips` anywhere. Looks like I have to install this software manually. How can I do it? Can't find anywhere in documentation…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the only way is to install it manually...